# What does meshed WiFi network benefit to user?

Tags: wireless

Why not just create multiple SSID? WiFi devices are capable to sense network drop and connect to new one.

Comment: In general, business networks (what is on-topic here) don't use mesh networks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Wireless mesh networks are an emerging technology right now. The use
>   of mesh wireless networks may bring the dream of a seamlessly
>   connected world into reality. Previously, it was thought to be near
>   impossible to easily, effectively and wirelessly connect entire cities
>   with inexpensive outdoor wifi technology. Wireless Mesh Networks allow
>   municipals, large enterprises, campus wireless networks and more to
>   achieve those goals.

*check this out it might help -*

http://www.securedgenetworks.com/blog/3-Key-Benefits-of-Wireless-Mesh-Networks